# Cannot find my SSD

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows on my SSD but it doesn't recognize the SSD disk. I'm trying to install it on my Acer Nitro 5 AN515-52-71X7 with windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

This is an overview of how I solved a similar issue on an Acer Aspire 3 (A315-56-533A), but it is rather brief since I don't have access to the laptop to check all the small details. Sorry! I still hope this helps someone else with this issue.

The underlying issue is similar to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1096035/307091). But on at least some Acer laptops there is an Acer specific trick to it.

In my case I don't remember how I set up the Kubuntu 20.04 USB thumb drive (possibly the dangerous `dd` method). I suspect multiple thumb drive solutions will work. Also I didn't need to meddle with secure boot and such.

Some of my sources had photos: [1](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/comment/892904/#Comment_892904), [2](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/comment/781191/#Comment_781191), [3](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2429951&s=7c75bda84e8c98430cafb88f661d019b&p=13900969#post13900969), [4](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/comments/feaekc/install_linux_on_an_acer_swift_3_sf31352_solution/)

1. Disable "fast startup" from Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options > System Settings. Alternatively this can maybe be done outside Windows as well - see step 7.
2. Update BIOS (probably only possible from within Windows).

If I understood user egydiocoelho correctly, step 3 helps keep Windows functional. I didn't try it, since I went Ubuntu only. If you also don't need Windows, you can continue from step 4.

3. <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> and type `msconfig`. Go to system startup and activate safeboot.
4. Press <kbd>F2</kbd> at boot time to get to the boot menu.
5. Navigate to the "Main" tab and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to reveal the hidden option.
6. Change the newly revealed "SATA Mode" to AHCI.
7. At the bottom, disable "Fast Boot" if you didn't do step 2.